Error calling Redshift stored procedure with refcursor parameter
I am trying to fetch resultset in DataGrip console from a Redshift stored procedure. Here is my stored procedure body
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_schema.get_redshift_table_ddl(
    p_schema_name IN VARCHAR,
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR,
    rs_out INOUT refcursor
)
AS $$
DECLARE
    v_query TEXT;
BEGIN

    OPEN rs_out FOR SELECT * FROM test_schema.test_table LIMIT 5;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;

I am calling the stored procedure in my console like this:
BEGIN;
CALL test_schema.get_redshift_table_ddl('test_schema','test_other_table','rs_out');
FETCH ALL FROM rs_out;
END;

Here is the AWS Reference that I am following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html
Error
When I am calling the stored procedure, I am getting the below error
ERROR: function format(character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. Where: SQL statement "SELECT FORMAT( $1 , $2 , $3 )"
Question
How can I pass the refcursor name while calling the stored procedure from console?

What happens when you try this in query editor in the aws console?

You should to use somewhere function format, that is not supported on Redshift. Function format is implemented in PostgreSQL 9.3. Amazon Redshift is based on some 8.x Postgres.
